# How to subscribe Google Analytics Segment from Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I use Google Analytics in an Android App. I want to create an mobile operator segment. (Verizone, AT&T, etc...)

I didn't find this selection in Google Analytics, is it possible from client (Android) side?

Answer (score 0):

TelephonyManager offers a public method [getNetworkOperator()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperator()).

In Firebase analytics, you can set custom user properties and set the values programmatically from you application as in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties).

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can i use this properties in Google Analytics?